# Modifying an XML Document Using C# Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have an application that loops through an XML then downloads the files from the urls in the file  My XML format is like this:

```
<FileDownloads>
<Downloads ID="1">
    <FriendlyName>MyFile</FriendlyName>
    <URL>http://www.MyDownloadURL.com?p=m/MyFileName</URL>
    <FileLocation>Tools\MyFIleName.exe</FileLocation>
<Selected>true</Selected>
<Switches></Switches>
</Downloads>
```

I am having trouble modifying elements of the XML IE: The Url if it changes and also adding and removing entire elements using Xelement.

I am trying the code Below:

```
public void NewXML()
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument XDocAdd = XDocument.Load(path);
            XElement DL = new XElement("Downloads");
            DL.Add(new XElement("FriendlyName", prl.textBox_FN.Text));
            DL.Add(new XElement("URL", prl.textBoxURL.Text));
            DL.Add(new XElement("FileLocation", prl.textBoxFL.Text));
            DL.Add(new XElement("Selected", prl.checkBox_DL.Checked));
            DL.Add(new XElement("Switches", prl.textBox_Switches.Text));
            XDocAdd.Element("FileDownloads").Add(DL);
           XDocAdd.Save(@"C:\Test\Test10.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(err.InnerException.ToString());
        }


    }
```

I am very much a noob so any help would be great!!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I have an existing XML doc that I would like to add/remove/change elements but I cant seem to get it to.

Comment: Why not? What happens? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XElement DL = new XElement("Downloads",
                  new XElement("FriendlyName", prl.textBox_FN.Text),
                  new XElement("URL", prl.textBoxURL.Text),
                  new XElement("FileLocation", prl.textBoxFL.Text),
                  new XElement("Selected", prl.checkBox_DL.Checked),
                  new XElement("Switches", prl.textBox_Switches.Text));
XDocAdd.Element("FileDownloads").Add(DL);
```

When you are creating XML with XElement you need to add them nested according to your schema.